# Anki AssertionError learning

Tags: python

Hi I have a problem with anki when using it I get the following error.
Anki 2.1.49 (dc80804a) Python 3.8.6 Qt 5.14.2 PyQt 5.14.2
Platform: Windows 10
Flags: frz=True ao=False sv=2
Add-ons, last update check: 2021-12-02 12:41:47

```
Caught exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “aqt\webview.py”, line 41, in cmd
File “aqt\webview.py”, line 142, in _onCmd
File “aqt\webview.py”, line 595, in _onBridgeCmd
File “aqt\reviewer.py”, line 503, in _linkHandler
File “aqt\reviewer.py”, line 423, in _answerCard
File “aqt\reviewer.py”, line 430, in _after_answering
File “aqt\reviewer.py”, line 211, in nextCard
File “aqt\reviewer.py”, line 317, in _showQuestion
File “anki\cards.py”, line 184, in autoplay
File “anki\decks.py”, line 309, in config_dict_for_deck_id
AssertionError
```

Comment: I think you should ask in the Anki forums

Comment: I tried but no one want to help me